# Method from an object in a list

Tags: c#, class, object, foreach

I have been searching for hours and I just can't seem to find any kind of answers. I'm trying to make `foreach` loop use a method inside of my object. Hopefully you can understand and help me.

**Warrior.cs:**

```
public void Info()
{
    Console.WriteLine("N: "
                      + this.name
                      + ", L: "
                      + this.level
                      + ", H: "
                      + this.health
                      + ", D: "
                      + this.damage
                      + ", A: "
                      + this.agility);
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
List<Warrior> lista = new List<Warrior>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    lista.Add(new Warrior("Swordman" + i.ToString()));
}

foreach (Warrior item in lista)
{
    lista.Info();//<----------This is where I get the error
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `item` and not `lista`. `lista` is the collection.

```
    foreach (Warrior item in lista)
    {
        item.Info();//<----------This is where i get the error
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The instance of the item is stored in `item`, not in the `lista`

```
foreach (Warrior item in lista)
{
    item.Info();
}
```

The forach calls the GetEnumerator() from the `lista` and stores each element of `lista` in `item`.

Look here for more info: *foreach, in* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `Info` method on `item`, not on the `lista` itself:

```
foreach (Warrior item in lista)
{
    item.Info();//
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is trying to run the Info() member of the LIST, where you want to run the member of one of the objects in the list.
Try this:

```
item.Info();
```

instead of

```
lista.Info();
```